# I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 HyperV role. I want to start browsing internet through PowerShell script.

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

Is there any way to start the browser (IE) through a PowerShell script?

If there is any way to do that please tell me in details because I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the regular `start iexplore`? It is not a specific PowerShell command.

PowerShell specific commands to start a program would be:

```
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start('<PATHTOPROGRAM>',"ARGUMENTS")
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start('C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe',"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Start-Process and give it your url (it will open in the default browser)

Start-Process http://google.com